# Unable to use butterknife in DroidWizard framework

Tags: android, mvp, butterknife

I am using [DroidWizard](https://github.com/praslnx8/DroidWizard) MVP framework for my android development and when I try to use butterknife library for dependency injection it is not working...

public class FriendsFragment extends CoreFragment implements FriendsCallBack
{
    private static final String TAG = FriendsFragment.class.getSimpleName();

```
@BindView(R.id.tab_layout)
protected TabLayout tabLayout;
@BindView(R.id.view_pager)
protected ViewPager viewPager;

private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

public static FriendsFragment newInstance()
{
    return new FriendsFragment();
}

@Override
protected FriendsPresenter setCorePresenter() {
    return new FriendsPresenter();
}

@Override
protected void initializeView(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    FriendsPagerAdapter friendsPagerAdapter = new FriendsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(friendsPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}


@Override
protected int getLayout()
{
    return R.layout.fragment_friends;
}

@Override
protected CorePresenter.CoreCallBack getCoreCallBack() {
    return this;
}
```

}

I am using Butterknife in a livrary project. I mean the butterknife library is places in another library

Comment: how you are using butterknife? can you please post some code here?

Comment: hey, I mean how you are initialing your butterknife library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot add butterknife in a library project. Instead use it in your main module app.. Please refer https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/45 for the library issue